# Group By doesn't work when sub queries in FROM and WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query that works.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  accnt_id,
  group_id
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      data ->> 'accountId' as accnt_id,
      data ->> 'resourceId' as group_id,
      jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'configuration' -> 'ipPerms') ->> 'toPort' as to_port
    FROM
      groups
  ) AS subquery
WHERE
  to_port :: integer IN (
    SELECT
      p.port
    FROM
      databases d
      JOIN ports p ON d.id = p.database_id
  );
```

I want to GROUP BY account_id

```
  SELECT 
    accnt_id,
    count(group_id) as num_of_group_ids
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        data ->> 'accountId' as accnt_id,
        data ->> 'resourceId' as group_id,
        jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'configuration' -> 'ipPerms') ->> 'toPort' as to_port
      FROM
        groups
    ) AS subquery
  WHERE
    to_port :: integer IN (
      SELECT
        p.port
      FROM
        databases d
        JOIN ports p ON d.id = p.database_id
    )
    GROUP BY accnt_id;
```

groups tables has two columns. id INT and data JSONB.
Here is the data column value.

```
[ { "accountId":"897687", "resourceId":"YHHH688", "configuration":{ "ipPerms":[ { "toPort":1234, "fromPort":0 } ] } }, { "accountId":"8760880", "resourceId":"FDFG688", "configuration":{ "ipPerms":[ { "toPort":5467, "fromPort":0 }, { "toPort":143, "fromPort":0 } ] } } ]
```

The query returns me no errors but also no data for count. Anything wrong am I doing here? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: please share some data, otherwise there is nothing to test/validate

Comment: Edit the question rather than add data to comments.

Comment: @Isolated done.

Comment: `... 'ipPerms') ->> 'toPort'...` I don't see _toPort_ in the JSONB you provided.

Comment: sorry my bad, there way a typo.

Comment: It works for me, so not sure why it's not working. One thought is taking an example port in all sources (such as 1234 is found) and change the end of the query to `WHERE to_port :: integer IN (SELECT 1234) GROUP BY accnt_id;` and see if it correctly counts.

Comment: Gosh! you are right. It works now without any changes (not even changing the ports SELECT query). I don't know why it didn't work for me before. Thanks @Isolated.